# Unity problems with classes C#

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have started learning Unity and already have learned JavaScript for web development so I do have some programming experience.

While programming in unity I came across a few things involving classes that I didn't quite get.

1) When I wright code as a component of a unity object I write it inside the public class shown below.  (name Mover is just an example.)  However I never create an instance of this class so how does this work?  All I see is the class being created.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {

}
```

2) Also shown in the code above is MonoBehaviour.  I read the api and it said it is a base class.  I never came across this in JavaScript.  What does this mean and what does it do to the class Mover?

Comment: You can easily search the web for "what is a base class".

Comment: I tried but I got a bunch of definitions that I didn't understand fully.  From what I got a base class is just a class that inherits nothing and other classes inherit its properties.  Is that right?

Comment: Drag and drop Mover.cs file to your GameObject. This is equivalent to making an instance of this class and attaching it to the GameObject.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Go to your project in Unity, create a c# script, name it whatever you want. Create a cube in your scene. Drag and drop this script onto the object. Open the script and you should see a start method and an update method.

Type Debug.Log("Start"); in the void Start() function, same in the void Update() method but change to the string to whatever. Click play in unity and watch the console.

You should see the console printing stuff.

Anything that is a child of Monobehaviour enables you to do a lot in which I am not going to get into here.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/

At the top, you can choose the language. Get used to that page. =D

Hope this leads you somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you may attach the script to a gameobject in the scene to use it.

For example,

```
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {
   private bool started = false;

   void Start () {
      Debug.Log ("Mover Started");
      started = true;
   }
}
```

If you attach this script to a gameobject in your scene and play the scene. The script will run and print out "Mover Started" and set the private boolean to true.

This are many other ways to interact with other objects or scripts too. Hope it clears things up a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at Unity's docs for [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) you'll see that every JS file associated with your project automatically derives from MB. If you're coding c#, understand that not everything must be a MB. Objects in the game hierarchy may only attach component scripts that inherit from MB objects. Unity handles the construction of these objects, and a MB is actually something that you are forbidden from constructing yourself.

Also, I think you might be better off at [unityAnswers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) for Unity related help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will check unityAnswers out :D